# jquery how to remove the first x div's?

Tags: jquery

i an trying to remove the first 4 divs if i click a button:

```
<div class="test">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="1"></div>
</div>
```

i;ve tried this, but it seems to remove them one by one:

```
if ($('.test').find('.1').size() >= 4) {
$('.test').find('.1').remove();
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [the `:lt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

```
$('.test').find('.1:lt(4)').remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/kR3wL/

**N.B.** "1" is not a valid class.

Comment: @Matt. This is really helpful. Thanks for that. if I need to add those remove divs again, how can i do so..?

Comment: @user2584538 maintain a reference to the elements returned by the `.remove()` call and `.add()` them later.

Comment: @Matt, yeah that works. I figured it out. Thanks Matt.:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector

```
$('div.1:lt(4)', 'div.test').remove()
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JD6CY/