# how to remove x p tags from a div

Tags: javascript, dom

i have a div that gets updated with javascript, the javascript adds new p tags into the div. to not get it messy i want to remove a defined ammount of p tags out of the div. how can i remove x p tags out of the div starting at the beginning of the div, so the first deleted will be

text

the second

text1

and so on?
the div looks like this:

```
<div id="messages">
<p>text</p>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
</div>
```

and please without jquery.
exact the same question is this one: [jquery how to remove the first x div's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558078/jquery-how-to-remove-the-first-x-divs)
but as it's there only with jquery it don't help me

thanks for your time :)

Comment: Can we see the javascript code that you've tried?

Comment: Remove the first element child of the `div` until you removed `x` elements (or there are no elements to remove).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let count = 0;

function add() {
  let messages = document.getElementById('messages');
  let newMessage = document.createElement('div');
  newMessage.innerText = 'text' + count;
  count++;

  messages.appendChild(newMessage);

  if (count > 5) messages.removeChild(messages.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="messages" class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"><button onclick="add()">Add</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way ;], I'm removing the last three `<p>`'s

```js
var div = document.getElementById('messages');
var removeItem = 3;
for(var i = div.children.length - 1; i >= removeItem; i--) {
  div.removeChild(div.children[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="messages">
<p>text</p>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
</div>
```